# Copying a file to a specific directory during installation using Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I have a file - say **readme.txt** that I want to copy or insert to a directory say

> C:\Documents and Settings\fooUsername\Application Data\BarSoftware

during the installation of my program using Visual Studio's setup project - I know it is something to do with **File System Editor** but not exactly sure as it has been some time since I have done this type of thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Right click your setup project ->
   View -> File System
2. Right click "File System on Target Machine" -> Add Special
   Folder -> User's Application Data
   Folder

   - All special folders are
     listed here
     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x
     but the "Application Data Folder" is
     the one that will put files in C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\
3. Right click "User's Application Data Folder" -> Add -> Folder
4. Name the new folder whatever you like (e.g. BarSoftware)
5. Right Click new folder (e.g. BarSoftware) -> Add -> File
6. Find your Readme.txt to add to that folder.

Answer (score 2):

For others that stumble across this, if you need a more general location (outside your application directory) see question:

[VS Setup project: install files in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499301/vs-setup-project-install-files-in-different-directories/17077899#17077899)