# VS Setup project: install files in different directories

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I have Visual Studio Setup project. And I want to install one of my file to some directory on drive C. How am I supposed to do it?

An example:

I'm installing my app in C:\MyApp. And one file, settings.ini, to C:\Settings\MyAppSettings\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using the [WindowsVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property:

- go to File System Editor
- right-click the "File System on Target Machine" tree item and select "Add Special Folder" -> "Custom Folder" context menu
- rename the new folder to something friendly, for example "C Drive"
- select the folder
- in its Properties pane set **DefaultLocation** to `[WindowsVolume]`
- in this custom folder add the folder structure you want (MyApp, Settings etc.)

Comment: To make it work I had to add a backslash at the end of DefaultLocation, hence: [WindowsVolume]\.

Comment: I have a file in D:\Insatller and need to copy it to D:\CSS\..\debug, but Didn't understand the procedure, as where the file to be copied is available in the first place and do we need to create folder structure like D->CSS->...->debug under custom folder?

Comment: I have a file in D:\Insatller and need to copy it to D:\CSS\..\debug, but Didn't understand the procedure, as where the file to be copied is available in the first place and do we need to create folder structure like D->CSS->...->debug under custom folder? Or do  I need to edit DefaultLocation property to D:\Installer or D:\CSS\..\debug?

Answer (score 3):

As this turned up quite high in the Google results - anyone looking to put the file onto a drive that is not the Windows volume (ie a network drive, or if Windows is not on C drive):

Follow the answer provided by @Cosmin above (add special folder in installer's file system), but put the literal drive path in.

Eg set **DefaultLocation** to `c:\MyApp` or `z:\desired\location`.

Comment: This answer is much useful than the accepted answer.