# During .Net Deployment, how to copy a file into a specific folder?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, vsto, setup-deployment

I am developing an AddIn for PowerPoint 2013 using vsto, vs ultimate 2013, and c#. During the deployment (using Msi Installer, or ClickOnce, or ClickTwice), how can I copy my data (files) from the project solution into a specific folder on the user's machine?

I am quite new to .Net. Sorry for my probably ignorance.

Comment: Try with the WindowsVolume property.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499301/vs-setup-project-install-files-in-different-directories/17077899#17077899

Comment: You can use post build trigger.
See [stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010

Comment: @VSharma No. The question is not how to copy files during development, but during *deployment*. This has nothing to do with Visual Studio post build triggers.

Comment: and how can I get the files from my project solution in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to include them to the installer as content files. See [Deploying an Office Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) for more information.

Also you may find the [How to deploy files with a clickonce application?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ed42712f-4855-469f-be3e-8470716fff37/action?threadDisplayName=windows&forum=winformssetup) forum thread helpful.

> Take those files out of your \bin\debug folder and add them to your project. You can either add them to the top level of your project, or put them in a folder under the top level of your project.
>   In the properties, set Build Action to 'content' and 'Copy to output directory' to "Copy always".
>   They will be deployed relative to the top level of the deployment folders.

Comment: There is no tutorial about how to copy file in the ClickTwice Deployment or Windows Installer? Anyway, your answer is good. It helps me to get the point where to start.

Comment: I'd suggest asking Setup & Deployments questions on the [ClickOnce and Setup & Deployment Projects](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/home?forum=winformssetup) forum. Pay special attention to the [Deployment FAQ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/407b0fad-dbbd-428f-ac0c-b6bc581b8620/deployment-faq?forum=winformssetup) .

Comment: The Deploying An Office Solution link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deploy 6 add-ins(word\excel\powerpoint) in one application. I gave up figuring this out and used Advanced Installer. It was quite easy to deploy everything using it, if you can absorb the cost that is.

Comment: There are several persons mentioning the Advanced Installer. Is this http://www.advancedinstaller.com/  ? The cost is too much.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right link. Professional version is more than enough for your requirements. Or you can try 30 day trial. It just makes installation really painless. But, you can surely do everything it does using Wix if you have time. If I am not wrong, Advanced installer is based on Wix.

Comment: at this price, I cannot purchase. So, probably that's good to know, but infeasible.